# AWS DMS Tasks fails after few days stating storage used by swap files exceeded the limit for task

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-dms, oracle-cdc

I am running 8-10 ongoing replication tasks in AWS DMS, with multiple tables inside each task. But one task in specific gets fails ~twice per week. It has a highly transactional table in which ~1 mil updates happen per 10 mins.

**Error-**

```
Reading from source endpoint temporary paused as total storage used by swap files exceeded the limit for task: abc-xyz
```

**Info in Cloudwatch -**

```
Reading from source is paused. Total storage used by swap files exceeded the limit 1048576000 bytes
```

All premigration assessments passed.

All the tables have a primary key and no LOB or CLOB cols in the task which gets failed.
Details of the task:

- Source -Oracle
- Target - Redshift
- Replication instance - dms.c5.2xlarge, single AZ
- Avg CPU utilization - ~35 %
- Using LOG miner technique.

**Task Setting JSON:**

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "IO"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SORTER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "REST_SERVER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMON"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "ADDONS"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMUNICATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-rep-instance-poc-3",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-abc-ongoing-task"
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "TTSettings": {
        "TTS3Settings": null,
        "TTRecordSettings": null,
        "EnableTT": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CommitRate": 10000,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DO_NOTHING"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 500,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 32,
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 8,
        "LobMaxSize": 32,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": true,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 500
    },
    "BeforeImageSettings": null,
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "StatementCacheSize": 50,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

Do it happen due to a single AZ instead of multi-AZ CPU or are there any other primary reason?

Comment: Do the frequent updates usually occur spread out, or are certain hours have more updates?  IE: Could the replication tasks be scheduled at certain hours?  Or smaller "batches"?  Out of swap space often means disk i/o, low memory, etc. etc.

Comment: yes usually in the daytime updates are more | No actually its ongoing replication needs to be running every time | All the memory is significantly large except swap memory of 2GB is there any way to increase that? @MarkStewart

Comment: I am having a similar problem did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Also having this same problem, did you find anythign @nvd